# What's the difference between looping through a sheet object by using sheet. Iterator() and foreach loop?

Tags: java, foreach, iterator, out-of-memory, xlsx

```
                    **EDITED**
```

I recently came across a strange occurance at my project in my workplace. I was working on a piece of code which is meant to read multiple xlsx files and then write multiple xlsx files by filtering the data.
However, one fine day, when I increased the input data, it started throwing Out of memory error. The stack trace was pointing me to the line number of for loop. When I changed the foreach to sheet. Iterator, it worked.
I am just curious to know how the error was resolved?
P. S : I was not modifying my sheet records in the foreach.

```
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> rit = sheet.iterator();
        //for (Row row : sheet) //<-- for each was throwing OOM
        while(rit.hasNext())
        {
            Row row=rit.next();



if(String.valueOf(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue()).equals("Pers.No."))
                listOfRecordsForHeader.add(row);

            if(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue().equals(personnelNumber) && !isEmptyRow(row)) {
                listOfRecords.add(row);
            }

    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Improving code so it doesn't throw Out of memory error is not a *performance* improvement. Space complexity and time complexity are entirely separate. Quite often, you have to worsen one to improve the other.

Comment: I am not quite sure as to why this question has been marked OFF Topic ? I am asking how sheet.iterator resolved teh OutOfMemory error and why the foreach was not working ? @Andreas

Comment: What foreach loop? I see no foreach loop in the question. **Show code!** Question is off-topic, because you don't show the code that doesn't work, so how are we to help you figure out why that is? Both the off-topic message, and the first comment, is asking for [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you follow that link and read it, you'll see it's all about showing **code** to us. Verifiable means that we can use the code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I understand your concerns. Its just that this piece of code was the working part of a larger code which I cannot post on this public forum. The looping used in this code is using iterator and it worked. However , while writing the same code using for each was not working and was throwing OutOfMemory error. My question was why wasnt the for loop working.